# Traversing through a list and compare 2 elements in it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a more efficient way to do this function (NO ZIP PLEASE). Hope I can get some feedback. I'm fairly new to python. But this is what I want my function  to do:

*Traverse through a list of numbers, and check if the elements in the list has a difference of 2. For those elements that has a difference of 2, append them to a list*

The output should look something like `[[3, 5], [5, 7], [11, 13], [17, 19]]`

My attempt is as follows: http://goo.gl/qmPkGK OR

```
def test(L):

    g = []

    #Traverse entire list starting from index 0 with increments of 1
    b = L[::1]
    print(b)

    #Traverse entire list starting from index 1 with increments of 1
    c = L[1::1]
    print(c)

    #For each element in range of my list given below,
    for i in range(0,len(L)-1):

    #checks if element in c minus element in b == 2
    #if yes, append both elements to k and then append that new list to list g
    if(abs(c[i]-b[i]) == 2):
        k = []
        k.append(b[i])
        k.append(c[i])
        g.append(k)
    print(g)
test([2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29])
```

What I did was, break the original list into 2 lists, list b and list c. For *list b*, traverse entire list starting from **index 0** with increments of 1 and for *list c*, traverse entire list starting from **index 1** with increments of 1. Now, I subtract elements in list c and elements in list b and check if their difference is 2. Then, append them to list k and have it appended to list g at the end. I was planning to have some sort of counter/pointer in the program that traverses the list and then find the difference between the numbers in the list and if satisfy difference of 2, append them. I tried but I failed. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def list_diff_2(lst):
  return [(lst[i - 1], lst[i]) for i in range(1,len(lst)) if abs(lst[i] - lst[i-1]) == 2]
```

Is this not simpler?

In general, I don't see any reason to make extra lists: usually, one loop through the original list would suffice.

Comment: Yes, I understand one loop is suffice, but I had no idea how to do it. I wanted to compare the elements in the indexes of the list if the difference was 2. But didn't know how to traverse it. So I ended up just breaking them. (: thanks. I will look through your code.